# Show that if E1 and E2 are subspaces of R n then E1 ∩ E2 is also a subspace of Rn . Is it true that E1 ∪ E2 is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I began by proving 0 belongs to E1 and E2, then E1 and E2 are closed sets. Then to prove that their intersection is also a subspace of Rn, I was thinking of proving that as something very obvious because the intersection will have contain the same elements. How do I prove the later part? Or am I proving the intersection part in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

No, $E_1\cup E_2$ is not a subspace. Consider $n=2$, $E_1$ spanned by $(1,0)$, and $E_2$ spanned by $(0,1)$. Then $E_1\cup E_2$ is not closed under addition: $(1,1)\not\in E_1\cup E_2$. The first statement is true, and is provable as you say and using the fact that each is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: thank you so much!